# Conexión a base de datos SQL Server a C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net

Estoy haciendo este código en C# y no me devuelve ningún registro, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

```
 try
 {
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\alopez\\Documents\\logs.txt"))
     {
         //
         SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
         conexion.ConnectionString = "Data Source = ***;" + "Initial Catalog=Onbase;" + "User id= ***;" + "password= ***;";
         conexion.Open();
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_Diskgroup", conexion))
         {
             SqlDataReader rd;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             SqlParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Diskgroupnum", Convert.ToInt32(NDiskgroup.Text));
             rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             if (rd.HasRows)
             {
                 sw.WriteLine("Número de registros: "+ rd.HasRows.ToString());
             }
             List<RegistroFirmas> rf = new List<RegistroFirmas>();
             while (rd.Read())
```

El SP que consulto es el siguiente:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_Diskgroup]
@Diskgroupnum int

AS

select ID.itemname, PP.lastuseddrive, filepath, PPL.diskgroupnum, DG.diskgroupname
  from hsi.itemdatapage IDP
       RIGHT JOIN (select distinct(diskgroupnum)
                     from hsi.physicalplatter
                    where physicalplatternum = 1
                          and lastuseddrive like '%\vmmeru\OnBaseII\%') PPL
           on IDP.diskgroupnum = PPL.diskgroupnum
       RIGHT JOIN hsi.physicalplatter PP on (PP.diskgroupnum = IDP.diskgroupnum
                                             and PP.physicalplatternum =1
                                             and PP.logicalplatternum = IDP.logicalplatternum)
       RIGHT JOIN hsi.diskgroup DG on (DG.diskgroupnum = IDP.diskgroupnum
                                       and PP.diskgroupnum = DG.diskgroupnum)
       INNER JOIN hsi.itemdata ID on ID.itemnum =IDP.itemnum
       LEFT JOIN hsi.archivedqueue AQ on (AQ.diskgroupnum = PP.diskgroupnum
                                          and PP.diskgroupnum =DG.diskgroupnum
                                          and ID.batchnum = AQ.batchnum)
 where DG.diskgroupnum =@Diskgroupnum
```

El resultado que me devuelve es que no encuentra registros.

Comment: Nunca compartas tu cadena de conexión. Incluso después de editado es visible. Cambia tu contraseña y si puedes también el IP del server

Comment: Puedes poner el código del Stored Procedure que estas ejecutando para ver si es eso lo que esta mal?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando ejecutas el SP en el sql server directamente, retorna resultados?

Comment: También decirte que `rd.HasRows` es un tipo `bool`, y no te va a devolver el número de registros que hay en el Reader.